# Requirements before jumping to OBIEE 11.7g

Tags: oracle, obiee

I'd like to know your opinions here, what tools do I have to learn first before studying OBIEE for ex. "Oracle Database" do I have to need a prior knowledge in Oracle Database in order for me to learn OBIEE in fast pace. I need your suggestions here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on what you want to do with OBIEE. You can be a reports developer, the metadata developer or an OBIEE Administrator. If you end up becoming a reports developer, you'll require less database knowledge. But to start off, you will require knowledge of

- Any one database (Oracle, mySQL etc)
- Dimensional modelling concepts

I've always believed in installing the software and filling the knowledge gaps while you're working on it.